# Adding element in an array within mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My Playerdata collection has an array field called Matches like so:-

```
const gsmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Edition6AuctionValue: Number,
    Edition6Seed: Number,
    Matches: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "matchregister"}]
});
```

After every match entry into the matchregister collection, I have access to the element in "data" via the callback function. I am now trying to add the _id field to the relevant player in the Playerdata collection above.

I am using FindOneAndUpdate in Mongoose and to achieve this I have tried using

```
$push
$addToSet
$set
```

I think the problem is syntax. The other elements that need to be updated in the Playerdata collection are getting updated without any issue. Its only this array field which is just coming blank.

Can someone help?

@anshu here is the code. Just before entering the loop, I did a console.log for matchid and I can see the ID object in console.

```
var matchid = data5._id;
                              GSM.findOneAndUpdate({Player_Name: req.body.player1},
                                                    {Total_Tournament_Matches_Played: wptournamentmatchesplayed,
                                                    Total_Tournament_Matches_Won: wptournamentmatcheswon,
                                                    Total_Tournament_Matches_Lost: wptournamentmatcheslost,
                                                    Total_Tournament_Matches_Points: wptournamentmatchpoints,
                                                    Total_Matches_Played: wptotalmatchesplayed,
                                                    Total_Matches_Won: wptotalmatcheswon,
                                                    Total_Matches_Lost: wptotalmatcheslost,
                                                    Total_Points: wptotalpoints,
                                                    Total_Games_Won: wptotalgameswon,
                                                    Total_Games_Lost: wptotalgameslost,
                                                    Winning_Percentage: wpwinningpercentage,
                                                    Player_FDR: wpfdr,
                                                    Total_Weighted_Points: wptotalweightedpoints},
                                                    {$push: {Matches: "matchid"}}, function(err,data6){
                                                      if(err){
                                                        console.log(err)
                                                      }
```

Comment: Hey your query is wrong i'm posting a new answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope it will help

Whenever you are using update query you need to use $set to tell mongodb that you are going to update these field and also i have used {new:true} so that you will get updated result in doc variable

```
 GSM.findOneAndUpdate({Player_Name: req.body.player1},
        {
          $set:{
               Total_Tournament_Matches_Played: wptournamentmatchesplayed,
        Total_Tournament_Matches_Won: wptournamentmatcheswon,
        Total_Tournament_Matches_Lost: wptournamentmatcheslost,
        Total_Tournament_Matches_Points: wptournamentmatchpoints,
        Total_Matches_Played: wptotalmatchesplayed,
        Total_Matches_Won: wptotalmatcheswon,
        Total_Matches_Lost: wptotalmatcheslost,
        Total_Points: wptotalpoints,
        Total_Games_Won: wptotalgameswon,
        Total_Games_Lost: wptotalgameslost,
        Winning_Percentage: wpwinningpercentage,
        Player_FDR: wpfdr,
        Total_Weighted_Points: wptotalweightedpoints
            },
            
            $push: {Matches: "matchid"}
        },{ new: true },function(err,doc){
          if(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
         })
```

Comment: this is the code I tried with $push but its not populating the Matches array. The only difference is the { new: true }. Will that impact the behaviour is anyway. Else I have already tested this and its still empty

Comment: It should work can you try printing your id which you are trying to push or may be check the condition which you are applying

Comment: i have edited my answer check it will help @SandeepNair

Comment: worked dude,,,thanks a ton and thanks for the explanation too

Comment: Welcome i'm glad it helped you

Comment: dude I have one more question - just a general query. I am new to mongo and node js...and this is my first project. In a couple of earlier modules in this project I have used the FindOneandUpdate and in there i am not using $set. Why then here? sorry I am just trying to be clear

Comment: @SandeepNair in your query you have chain of update like first you want to update certain field and then you want to push to array in that case we need to specify what are all the fields we have to update using $set and push on another hand in other queries you would have been only updating fields so basic syntax is Playerdata.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,callback); by default in other it worked even though if you haven't used $set because mongoose by default wrap them into $set whatever you pass into second option

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
`db.Playerdata.findOneAndUpdate({Edition6Seed:10},{$push:{Matches:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "matchregister"}}})`.
This worked locally in mongo shell.